# Question on Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $m$ men and $n$ monkeys. If a man can have any number of monkeys, then, in how many ways can every monkey have a master?

The usual solution is given by this method:-
The first monkey can select it's master in $m$ ways. The same with the second, third...Till the $nth$ monkey. Total number of ways become:-

$m×m×....$($n$  times) $=m^n$ ways.

The way I approached the problem is different. I imagined $n$ identical boxes with monkeys in it. The monkeys can be arranged in $n!$ ways inside the boxes. Now I distribute the boxes to $m$
men such that every man gets an $x_r$ number of boxes. This can be found by the number of solutions of this equation:-

$x_1+x_2+x_3+......+x_m =n$.

Where ${x_1 , x_2 ,......, x_m} $ are non negative integers.

Which comes out to be

$^{m+n-1}C_{m-1}$

So the final result becomes $n!×^{m+n-1}C_{m-1}$. I know this isn't the correct answer. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: are the monkeys distinguishable are the men distinguishable ? etc. that factors into things about order. 482219923991114978843459072919892677776312893440000000 possible ways to put all 32 pieces on a chessboard for example once you realize that knights rooks and pawns of the same color are all indistinguishable from a certain number of other pieces that drops to 18538906782351238564768183929293142681600000 which cuts the number by a factor of more than 10 billion, before considering legality.

Comment: Yes they are distinct. But I'm not pretty sure about this. Seems from the usual solution that they are distinct.

Comment: What do the boxes contribute?  You seem to have exactly one monkey per box.

Comment: @RossMillikan . Yes there's one monkey per box. As for the boxes I don't know what the actually contribute.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the second approach is that it overcounts all situations where the same man owns two (or more) monkeys, since it shouldn't matter which order monkeys with the same master go in, but you always count all orderings of the monkeys as different.

(In the simple case where there are two monkeys and two men, you count both the situation where monkey 1 goes in box 1, monkey 2 in box 2, and man 1 gets both boxes and the situation where monkey 1 goes in box 2, monkey 2 goes in box 1, and man 1 gets both boxes, but these have the same effect.)

Comment: I need a bit more satisfactory explanation.

Comment: @gowreeshmago:  handcount the two monkey two man case.  The book solution says there are $2^2=4$ cases.  Man 1 can get none, monkey 1, monkey 2, or both for four.  Your answer is $2!^3C_1=6$ because you count twice the case where Man 1 gets nothing and the case where Man 1 gets both.  You count the two orders of giving them to Man 1 or Man 2 as different, making six.

Comment: @RossMillikan I understand what you say.. that's why I've mentioned that the answer is wrong. If you plug in the values of m=9and n=11 the first approach will give you an answer 31381059609 but the second one will give you an answer 75582. So according to you if I'm over counting the cases in my approach I would have got an answer greater than the usual approach which is not so in this case. Which means I'm missing cases.

Comment: @gowreeshmago no it won't. Your formula of $n!\times {}^{m+n-1}\mathrm C_{m-1}$ is equal to $(m+n-1)\times(m+n-2)\times\cdots\times m$, which is always going to be bigger than the correct solution $m^n$ (it has $n$ terms, and they're all at least $m$).

Comment: Well I've done the math on it.. if you doubt please do the same..

Comment: For $m=9$ and $n=11$ your formula gives $3016991577600$, not $75582$.

Comment: (and this is about $100$ times bigger than the correct answer)

Comment: [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=11!(19+choose+8)) is the Alpha calculation supporting Especially Lime's value

Comment: Ah, it seems $75582$ is what you get if you miss out the $n!$ term. Without the $n!$ term you are treating the monkeys as indistinguishable, so you obviously get an answer which is far too small.

Comment: @gowreeshmago:  you are forgetting the factor $11!$ in your formula.  That has two zeros at the end.

Comment: with a  factor of n!,  n! always has a 0 at the end if n>5 also if 15 and an even number are involved the result will be an even multiple of 5 if all even parts of the product on top are not cancelled.

Comment: @EspeciallyLime ok. I'm sorry. I deviated from my actual result by missing the terms. So do you mean I'm over counting the cases?

Comment: You are canceling the $11!$ twice.  When you compute $^{19}C_8$ it should be $\frac {19!}{11!}{8!}$  You canceled the $11!$ already when you stopped multiplying at $12$ in the numerator, then you canceled it again.

Comment: Yes, you are overcounting.  Look at my handcount for the  two man two monkey case.  I showed *explicitly* where your overcount is

Comment: @RossMillikan yeah I realise that now..

Comment: Yes, you are always overcounting the cases, for the reason I gave in my answer. You can simplify your formula to be a product of $n$ terms of which the smallest is $m$, so it's easy to prove that your formula will always be bigger (provided you have at least two monkeys).

Comment: Your formula will overcount each case by the product of the factorials of the number of monkeys that each man gets.